# How is prize money taxed in India?

Tags: united-states, taxes, india, dtaa

I have won a programming competition based in US, and i will be getting $800 from the US based company. They are telling me that they will pay the taxes already and will give me the full amount. Now, would i have to pay special 30% tax to Indian govt. also?

I've searched over internet but could not reach any conclusion. From what i have researched, there is DTAA b/w India and US, and i believe my earning will be regarded as prize money and will be eligible for special 30% tax. Also i am a resident of India and i am a student who never paid tax earlier.

I think the tax can be avoided under DTAA? Can someone please tell the procedure or tell me where i am wrong? Also what is the best way to not pay double tax as paying company is already paying taxes to US govt.

Answer (score 1):

> programming competition based in US, and i will be getting $800 from the US based company.

Ensure that this is not a scam.

> I've searched over internet but could not reach any conclusion. From what i have researched, there is DTAA b/w India and US, and i believe my earning will be regarded as prize money and will be eligible for special 30% tax. Also i am a resident of India and i am a student who never paid tax earlier.

Prize money is taxed at highest tax bracket irrespective of the income; this is currently around 34%. Under DTAA you can claim the benefit of taxes paid in the US. So effectively you may have to pay additional 4% tax in India as 30% is already paid in US. Please apply for a PAN card so that you can file the appropriate returns.

Comment: What are the documents i need to ask from them at time of payment in order to avail tax benefits under DTAA?

Comment: @jokerster Don't know.

Comment: "30% is already paid in US". The 30% has been _withheld_, and is a credit towards the actual tax _liability_ of the OP, who might get a refund if the actual US tax liability is less that what has been withheld.  What is taxable income in India is the _full amount_ of the prize, not what has been _received_ from the company (actual prize less the US income tax withholding).

Comment: @DilipSarwate good point.